# Probability of randomly selecting an $a$ from a sequence of length $n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Assume a string '$abababababa......$' and so on with every $a$ being followed by $b$ and vice versa. If I were to randomly stop at the $n$th element of this string and randomly select a letter from this substring what is the probability of the event that this letter drawn is an $a$.

Take $E$ to be the event of drawing an $a$. The probability of $n$ being odd is $1/2$ and when $n$ is odd, since the string begins with $a$, the probability of drawing an $a$ is $(n +  1)/2n$. When $n$ is even, the probability is just $1/2$ because equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s.

So taking $P(E)=P(n=even)*P(E|n=even) + P(n=odd)*P(E|n=odd)$ gives us

$P(E) = 1/2*(1/2) + 1/2*((n+1)/2n)$.

On substituting values for $n$, one can very easily see that this expression is wrong. The obvious correct expression would act on conditions such as in

$P(E)=(n+1)mod(2)*(1/2) + (n)mod(2)*((n+1)/2n)$

where only one expression would be used based on the condition on $n$.

My question here is - what exactly went wrong in the first way of calculating. I found it very easy to explain the second approach but find it quite hard to explain why exactly the first approach is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The probability will be a piecewise function here depending on the parity of $n$. In your first method, what you are claiming is that when we choose the value of $n$ both events ($n$ being even and $n$ being odd) will contribute to the occurrence of event $E$, which is definitely not the case. Once you stop at a certain $n$, depending on it's parity, the other case will not even occur.

Comment: It is unclear whether you want a conditional probability given $n$ (which you have already computed correctly as $1/2$ when $n$ is even, and $(n+1)/(2n)$ when $n$ is odd), or an unconditional probability over the randomness in $n$. In the latter case, your answer should not depend on $n$, but you also have to specify exactly what "randomly selecting $n$" means. One concrete nitpick: $P(E \mid N=\text{odd})$ is not $(n+1)/(2n)$; this quantity is the conditional probability $P(E \mid N=n, \text{n is odd})$.

Comment: Without knowing the distribution you use to select $n$ there is no way to answer the  overall question.

Comment: @lulu Say probability of chosing an $n$ is uniformly distributed between the first 100 numbers i.e $[1, 100]$ - The probability of it being odd and even would still be $1/2$

Comment: Yes, but now you can sum each case, so the answer is $\frac 1{100}\times \sum_{n=1}^{100}p_n$  where $p_n$ is the probability of getting $a$ given the cutoff was $n$ (which you have already computed).

Comment: @lulu Essentially the problem with the first approach being that I cannot form a distribution on random variable $n$ because of its infinite domain and that I cannot write the conditional probability on odd and even but would have to for every numbersince the probability is different?

Comment: Well, the sum splits as $\sum_{n\,even}+\sum_{n\,odd}$ so you should have a sum.

Comment: To your broader point:  yes.  one difficulty here is that there is no obvious distribution to chose.

Comment: @lulu In that case If i were to not give a range of values for $n$ to take and yet call it uniformly distributed, the question would not have a valid solution because n cant be uniformly distributed over infinite values - making even the second answer deceptively wrong?

Comment: I don't understand either of your answers, since they depend on $n$.  The only answer I'd except without a distribution would be $\frac 12$ , if the premise was that you were only going to choose an enormous value of $n$.

Comment: @lulu or 0 since $n$ can never be sampled from a uniform distribution over an infinite set?

Comment: No...I don't see $0$ as plausible, since for no $n$ is the answer $<\frac 12$.  But, really, it's best to just specify a distribution.